# python cherrypy session usage example of cherrypy.lib.sessions

Tags: python, session, save, cherrypy

I am  total newbie with cherrypy.
My setup: Arch Linux, Python 3.3, tornado, cherrypy 3.2

Trying to implement session handling for a web app using `cherrypy.lib.sessions` (for some reason often referred to as cherrypy.sessions in various forums, might be another version)

I am looking for an example of the following:

- instantiate a session object
- set a value of an arbitrarily named attribute
- write session into a session file
- read session info from session file
- access the the value of the modified attribute

My (relevant) code:

```
import cherrypy

class RequestHandlerSubmittedRequest(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    SetState(self)

def SetState(self):
  cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True})
  cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.storage_type': 'file'})
  #directory does exist  
  cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.storage_path': '/tmp/cherrypy_sessions'}) 
  cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.timeout': 60})    
  cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.name': 'hhh'})
```

So far so good. Now:

```
  obj_session = cherrypy.lib.sessions.FileSession
```

Here I get the first snag (or misunderstanding). 
The returned obj_session contains no session ID of any kind, just an empty object frame. Also: no file is created at this point in /tmp/cherrypy_sessions - 
should not it be there now? I would expect it to be created and named after its session ID.

OK, no ID in the object, let's assign one:

```
  session_id = obj_session.generate_id(self)
```

This returns a long random string as it should I guess

And now I don't know how to proceed with assignments and saving calling    `obj_session.save()` or `obj_session.load()` with several variations of input gives `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute X"` where X can be `"load"` and couple of other keywords. Passing `self` or `obj_session` itself to the methods does not help, just changes the wording of the error. I must be going in a very wrong direction in general.

So, is there an example of those five steps above? I could not find one anywhere.

Thanks.

Igor